# How to load data using xml on button over in flash

Tags: xml, flash

I'm new to FLASH so not having any ideas how to load simply xml to show data on mouse over.

Comment: and when you searched you found what......?

Answer (score 0):

Here is good example:

http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3xml/

Read the tutorial and try it yourself. Ask more if you have still problems..